# How do you find Slices in Sketch - is finding Exportables the only way?

Tags: export, icon, sketch-app, slices

### The Problem

I want a way to find Slices in a complex Sketch document.

### Why this is a problem

I have used icon templates from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/) and [Apply Pixels](https://applypixels.com/resource/ios16appicon) which are pre-configured to export different icon sizes.

These are often configured with the slices deeply nested, as seen in the screenshot below, so I wanted a search capability.

### Possible Workaround

There's a dropdown in the Search box (top of Layer panel) which allows you to choose `Exportable` and has the slice icon next to it.

However, that does what it says, finding **exportable** assets including non-slices marked as Exportable.

Is Exportable taken as a synonym for Slice, given that you cannot have a non-exportable Slice?

(Artboards you have made exportable allow you to remove all their export presets, going back to a non-exportable status. Slices will not allow you to remove the last export preset of a list.)

### Why the workaround is insufficient

If you use these templates as a starting point, it's OK because they are completely slice-oriented. However, I also have complex documents that used Artboards as the main exportable element. I want a way to find just the Slices in those documents.

[image: Portion of layer view showing nested slice]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Sketch Twitter support](https://twitter.com/SketchHelp/status/1637792532997320704)

The answer is to use the [Automate plugin](https://github.com/Ashung/Automate-Sketch/)

`Layer - Select Layers in Selection By Type - Slices`

[image: Screenshot showing the Automate Plugin navigating down through Layer - Select Layers in Selection By Type - Slices]